# Will someone explain this javascript REGEX pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
src.match(/^(https?\:\/\/.*)\//)
```

I know regular expressions but the syntax is not familiar to me. Can somebody explain to me what it's matching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matches anything that starts with `http://` *or* `https://` followed by any number of any character (`.*`), followed by another `/` slash.

The `/` slashes need to be escaped. I don't know why the colon is escaped too.

Comment: In addition to this, the `.*` is done greedily, so `<a href="http://mysite.com/mypage.php">go to mypage</a>` will result with `http://mysite.com/mypage.php">go to mypage<` in match[1].  I'm not saying this regex is flawed in that fashion, you just need to be aware of it when using.

Answer (score 4):

- `^` start of string
- `(` start of a capture group

  - `http` the characters "http"
  - `s?` zero or one of the character "s"
  - `\:` a colon character *(escaped, though not necessary)*
  - `\/\/` two forward slash characters *(escaped so that it doesn't close the regex literal)*
  - `.*` zero more more of any character, except a line break
- `)` end of the capture group
- `\/` a forward slash chararacter *(escaped so that it doesn't close the regex literal)*

---

The starting and ending `/` characters simply denote regular expression literal notation.

Answer (score 1):

A string that starts with "http"/"https", followed by ://, followed by any number of characters (greedily), and then by a trailing /.

The match itself will be exactly what's searched, minus the last /.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty ordinary regex:

`^` At the start of the string

`(` Start a capture

`http` Match "http" literally

`s?` Match an optional "s"

`\:` Match a literal colon

`\/` Match a literal slash

`\/` Match a literal slash

`.*` Then as many characters as possible

`)`  End the capture

`\/` Ending at a literal slash

The regex has the effect of capturing the protocol, host, and path from a URL and excluding any file at the end. For instance in the case of `https://www.host.com/path/to/my/file.cgi`, `https://www.host.com/path/to/my` would be captured.

Answer (score 1):

These are some examples of what would that regex match:

```
https://www.aaa.bb/
http://www.aaa.bb/
http://some.server/
http://aa/
http:///
https:///
http:////////////
https:////////////
```